# Why does my Code show Error message as Failed to make request: Request failed with status code 404 even though it is correct

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, visual-web-developer

`So i have been making a website which shows the Type of activity and participants based on the options selected from Drop down menu.
But even if i choose anything it shows me the error as "Failed to make request: Request failed with status code 404" in console and the website keeps displaying 'No activites match your criteria'

This is my  Index.js file

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// Step 1: Make sure that when a user visits the home page,
//   it shows a random activity.You will need to check the format of the
//   JSON data from response.data and edit the index.ejs file accordingly.
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/random");
    let result = response.data;
    console.log(result);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      data: result
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to make request:", error.message);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    const type = req.body.type;
    const participants = req.body.participants;
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/filter? 
    type=${type}&participants=${participants}`
    );
    const result = response.data;
    console.log(result);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      data: result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)],
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to make request:", error.message);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      error: "No activities that match your criteria.",
    });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

and my here is my index.ejs file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
  <title>I'm Bored</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Let's find something for you to do ✌️</h1>

    <form action="/" id="form" class="form" method="POST">
      <select name="type" class="form-select">
        <option value="" data-display="Select">Random type</option>
        <option value="education">Education</option>
        <option value="charity">Charity</option>
        <option value="recreational">Recreational</option>
        <option value="relaxation">Relaxation</option>
        <option value="busywork">Busywork</option>
        <option value="social">Social</option>
        <option value="diy">DIY</option>
        <option value="music">Music</option>
      </select>
      <select name="participants" class="form-select">
        <option value="">Any number of people</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" class="form-submit">Go</button>
    </form>
    <section id="cards" class="cards">
      <% if(locals.data){ %>
      <article class="card-item">
        <h2 class="card-activity">
          <%= data.activity %>
          <!-- Show Activity -->
        </h2>
        <div class="card-info">
          <span class="card-type">
            <%= data.type %>
            <!-- Show Activity type -->
          </span>
          <span class="card-participants">
            participants: <%= data.participants %>
            <!-- participants: Show participant number -->
            <span class="card-number"></span>
          </span>
        </div>`your text`
      </article>
      <% } %>


      <%if(locals.error){%>
      <div id="tag-error" class="tag-error">
        <%=error%>
        <!-- Show any errors that were sent from the backend -->
      </div>
      <% } %>

    </section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What did `console.error("Failed to make request:", error.message);` print in the terminal? You are sending a form via http which is sent via the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so your `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded extended: true}));`will parse the form for you and make the data available in the `req.body` object which you seem to have done correctly. Did `console.log(req.body);` show your form data in the terminal?

Comment: Yes it does,it sends out the info as{ type= "whatever was selected from first drop down" and participants also does the same}

Comment: So are you getting the `No activities that match your criteria` message sent back to your front-end? If so that means an error was thrown and you look to be logging that error. What does it say?

Comment: Even logging the error said the same thing earlier but now its working fine,thank you.

Comment: I suspect the API you are using has a rate limit on it where you can only make so many requests within a certain time period or some of your queries didn't find any data. I would recommend you check the `response.status` is `200` before you assume `response.data` has data.

Answer (score -1):

**You can add app.use(express.json()) in order to parse JSON data coming from the request. Write these codes respectively:**

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
```

Comment: Doesn't using axios parse JSON files already?

Comment: @TylerDurden, yes, Axios does parse JSON files already, but writing app.use(express.json()) generally works for me.

Comment: @TylerDurden, did using app.use(express.json()) solve your issue?

Comment: `express.json()` parses data sent from the front-end as json encoded. Typically from a `fetch/axios` post request so won't be of any use since OP looks to be sending a normal http form which will be in either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default) or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I don't exactly know what worked but I did not use app.use(express.json()). Now the code is running all fine.Thank you guys